# Can we create a "WiFi server" in our computer, in order to avoid using the actual wifi network to send data?

Tags: linux, networking, wifi

I live at a hostel, and would like to share files from Phone to Laptop, maybe also to use WiFi without the phone being directly connected to the network.

Weeks ago file-sharing  was accomplished by setting up a Samba server installing a client in the phone.

This was much like the way the web works, you set up a HTTP-server, and devices need a HTTP-client. As long as the networks are interconnected this works.

But the Samba server was using the hostel's Router to Route requests between devices.

I'm aware that, if encryption is enabled this should be secure.

**Question**

But is there a way to create a own WiFi service on my Laptop ( I don't know how to call it) so the request does not use the Home Router/Network and connect to it?

(I'm using Linux).

Comment: That's an `ad-hoc` wireless connection. There are many ways to set it up and the possibility of running it might depend on your system and hardware. See this for example (if you are in Linux): https://www.toysdesk.com/articles/creating-an-ad-hoc-wireless-connection-with-linux/

Comment: It's called a mobile hotspot. I didn't created one with linux yet (different thing as a ad-hoc network). but it is only possible if the network hardware supports this mode of operaiton. On windows it's called mobile hotspot.